# Substitute for ground picnic ham.

Tags: substitutions

Can’t find 1/2lb ground picnic ham to use in pasta sauce recipe. What could I use as a substitute?

Answer (score 1):

You could use ground pork, ground beef, ground lamb, or ground chicken.  These would slightly alter the flavor of the final product, depending on the other ingredients in your sauce.